# Can I use windows documents after install linux?

Tags: windows

As the title, Can I use windows documents after install linux ?

Comment: What documents (formats)? Can you access them but not open, or are you not able to access them at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about standard document formats like pdf, doc or xls files, they can be viewed/edited using LibreOffice and evince.